# How to calculate size of a folder located on different machine(Remote) in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, file, t-sql

and i am using following script code, but its not working..

```
DECLARE @TenantId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ='A79ED820-2E5E-4A9D-B930-B7597DC97081'
DECLARE @BusinessName VARCHAR(200) 

declare @line  varchar(255) =''
declare @path varchar(255)=''
declare @command varchar(255)=''
DECLARE @folderSizeGB decimal (16,8) = 0

DECLARE @AttachmentDiscSpaceUsed decimal (16,8) = 0
```

-- Code to calculate folder size in GB BEGINs

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
drop table #temp

create table #temp (line varchar(255))

set @path = '\\ewp-dev18\\c$\\Attachments\\' +  CONVERT(varchar(50),@tenantId)           
set @command = 'dir "' + @path +'"' 

insert into #temp
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @command

select @line=
ltrim(replace(substring(line, charindex(')', line)+1,
len(line)), ',', ''))
from #temp where line like '%File(s)%bytes'

SET @line=
(Case WHEN @line IS NULL or @line ='' THEN '0' ELSE @line END) 

set @folderSizeGB  = Cast(Replace(@line,'bytes', '') as decimal)/1073741824
if (@folderSizeGB is null ) 
    set @folderSizeGB =0   
    SET @AttachmentDiscSpaceUsed = @folderSizeGB              
    SET @path=''
    SET @command=''
    SET @line=0
-- Drop #temp table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    drop table #temp
```

-- Code to calculate folder size in GB ENDs

please help.. thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested but your path is looking locally for your remote machine ?

```
set @path = '\\ewp-dev18\\c$\\Attachments\\' +  CONVERT(varchar(50),@tenantId)
```

should be

```
set @path = '\\\\ewp-dev18\\c$\\Attachments\\' +  CONVERT(varchar(50),@tenantId)
```

You should also include the error message you're getting.

Comment: I tried this, but it is raising "Access is denied" error message. but i have all access to that remote machine. do i need to pass login credential with it ?? if yes than what will be the script for it ??